# DocumentDb optimizing the resume of a non-partitioned change feed

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am creating an un-partitioned change feed that I want to resume e.g. poll for new changes every X seconds.  The checkpoint variable below holds the last response continuation response.

```
    private string checkpoint;

    private async Task ReadEvents()
    {
            FeedResponse<dynamic> feedResponse;
            do
            {
                feedResponse = await client.ReadDocumentFeedAsync(commitsLink, new FeedOptions
                {
                    MaxItemCount = this.subscriptionOptions.MaxItemCount,
                    RequestContinuation = checkpoint
                });

                if (feedResponse.ResponseContinuation != null)
                {
                    checkpoint = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;
                }

               // Code to process docs goes here...

            } while (feedResponse.ResponseContinuation != null);
    }
```

Note the use of the "if" block around the checkpoint.  This is done because if I leave this out the responseContinuation gets set to null, which will basically restart the polling cycle as setting the request continuation to null will pull the 1st set of documents in the change feed.

However, the downside is each polling loop will replay the previous set of documents rather than just any additional changes.  Is there anything I can do in order to optimized this further or is this a limitation of the change feed API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read change feed, you must use `CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery` (which never resets ResponseContinuation), instead of `ReadDocumentFeed` (which sets to null when there are no more results).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-change-feed#working-with-the-rest-api-and-sdk for a sample.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I've been referring to.  I was just hoping we could do this via the ReadDocumentFeed operation rather than having to read partition ranges (as we don't need to scale out reading the feed across multiple readers, but we will have a partitioned collection).

I think what threw me was the "Performing an incremental ReadDocumentFeed" section in the article, but upon a reread from a .NET SDK operation it's referring to the query operation you mention.

Comment: Also worth adding - is there any reason why the CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery method isn't on the IDocumentClient interface?  I am using version 1.11.1 of the NuGet package.  I have to use the DocumentClient class directly.

Comment: We left it out of IDocumentClient because adding new methods might lead to compilation errors for developers who had implemented a mock over IDocumentClient. But this has been a popular request, so we'll add it in an upcoming release.

Comment: And thanks for feedback about ReadDocumentFeed not supporting incremental reads. We'll look at adding it in an update to the SDK.